# Get substring between 2 specific sequence of characters from text

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a long text in which are several special characters, so I cannot filter to `"` or `)` characters.
Needed text and its position:

```
(Job:
"THIS TEXT")
```

I tried to get THIS TEXT with following code:

```
var jobstring = jobname.substring(jobname.indexOf("(Job: \"") + 7)
jobstring = jobstring.substring(0, jobstring.indexOf("\")"));
```

and this code too:

```
var jobstring=jobname.substring(jobname.lastIndexOf("Job: ")+7,jobname.lastIndexOf("")"));
```

None of those output is THIS TEXT, but I don't know exactly what I missed.

Comment: 1: You have a line break (`\n` or `\r\n`). 2 This cannot be right `jobname.lastIndexOf("")")` - do you mean `jobname.lastIndexOf('")')` - please show a longer string including what is before and after the JOB and THIS TEXT

Comment: works fine for me if the input is `'(Job: \
"THIS TEXT")'`

Comment: Why not use regex? `/(?!Job:.{1}\")[\w ](?=\"\))/gm`. [Sample](https://www.regex101.com/r/QRGrcM/1)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3pnm35Lp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use regex?

```js
var s = '(Job:\n"THIS TEXT")';
var rx = /Job:\s*"([^"]*)"/g
console.log(rx.exec(s)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no space after job: but a ligne break.
you'll have to use a regexp with \n \r, or \s witch is for all blank space.

```
    result = jobname.match(/Job:\s"(.+)"/g);
```

I suggest you to use a regexp tool, you will find many of them. 
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regexp+tool&ia=web